# EEPROM in battery management system

Tags: eeprom, bms

I am designing a battery management system. I am however unable to comprehend the way in which EEPROM can be accessed to feed OCD (Over Current Delay) values.
I have attached the datasheet:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq77915.pdf?ts=1640062055629&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.in%252F

[image]

Edit: I found this in page 21 of datasheet.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EEPROM can't be accessed by users, it is factory programmed.

https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management-group/power-management/f/power-management-forum/941651/bq77915-bq77915x-custom-eeprom-programming

Comment: Please refer "EDIT" in main post.

Comment: @BlackHawk What you quoted does not mean the EEPROM is user programmable. TI can program the EEPROM in any way they want during production. All the different BQ77915XX devices are identical parts that are just factory programmed with different values into EEPROM. See page 14 of the datasheet where it says that settings are factory-programmed in the detailed chip description.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!